# Flutter firebase messaging gives registerPlugin exception in Android

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Everything was fine until the last Flutter upgrade to beta 2.0.1 (same as current stable I think).

Now I suddenly get this message during init of the firebase messaging.

```
NoSuchMethodError: No top-level getter '_registerPlugins' declared.
Receiver: top-level
Tried calling: _registerPlugins
```

This error is triggered by calling:

```
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
```

Down the call path this calls:

```
package: firebase_messaging_platform_interface-1.0.0-dev.10
file   : method_channel_messaging.dart:

await channel.invokeMapMethod('Messaging#startBackgroundIsolate', {
          'pluginCallbackHandle': bgHandle.toRawHandle(),
          'userCallbackHandle': userHandle.toRawHandle(),
});
```

That ends up in:

```
package: flutter
file   : platform_channel.dart:

final ByteData? result = await binaryMessenger.send(
  name,
  codec.encodeMethodCall(MethodCall(method, arguments)),
);
```

Seems like the exception is thrown here...

Those are the messages it generates in my console. Nothing that indicates a problem I think:

```
I/FLTFireBGExecutor( 8226): Creating background FlutterEngine instance, with args: [--start-paused, --enable-dart-profiling]
D/EGL_emulation( 8226): eglCreateContext: 0xe3b20600: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation( 8226): eglCreateContext: 0xe3b206c0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/HostConnection( 8226): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xc4abc480, tid 8310
D/HostConnection( 8226): HostComposition ext 
  ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 
  ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem 
  ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 
  ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands 
  ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings 
  ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements 
  ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer 
  ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync 
  ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 
  ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_vertex_array_object 
  GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing 
  ANDROID_EMU_async_frame_commands ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
D/EGL_emulation( 8226): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe3b206c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe3bb0b50)
>>> At this moment the exception is thrown <<<
I/FLTFireMsgService( 8226): FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundService started!
```

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: I found that downgrading Flutter to version 1.25.0-8.3.pre solves the problem. So this might be due to incompatibility between the libraries I use and the Flutter version.

Comment: Probably some of my libraries are not compatible. I'm using Chopper and so can't upgrade all.
 https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/plugin-api-migration