# No top-level getter '_registerPlugins' declared error

Tags: getter, nosuchmethoderror, toplevel

I get this error every 5 ~ 10 minutes while running my app.

[image]

My app doesn't stop or anything, but I think something needs to be done.
What is wrong and what should be done to avoid this error?

Comment: Have the same problem. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: Are you using firebase?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66504400/flutter-firebase-messaging-gives-registerplugin-exception-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some part of your code is calling registerPlugins, which is no longer needed... We need find out which package calls that and update it.

Comment: Thanks ykonda. How can I find out which package calls it?